# Java's Arrays.fill() with multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have a large 2D array:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[10000][1000];
```

The program needs to use frequently:

```
Arrays.fill(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int val);
```

But sometimes it need to fill a row, and sometimes a column.
For example, I can fill a row 200 by 1 from 10 to the end:

```
Arrays.fill(matrix[200], 10, 1000, 1);
```

But how to fill a column without `for()`?
Is there a data structure that allows to perform both operation with speed, comparable to `Arrays.fill()` ?

Comment: @MattBall, I don't think so. The question is about filling the other dimension, i.e. `matrix[0][0]`, `matrix[1][0]`, etc....

Comment: It's all the same. You have to use a for loop, either implicitly or explicitly. `Arrays.fill()` just happens to hide the loop from you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you look at the source code (which is copied below) for `Arrays.fill()` you will find that its only a for loop.

```
public static void fill(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int val) {
    rangeCheck(a.length, fromIndex, toIndex);
    for (int i=fromIndex; i<toIndex; i++)
        a[i] = val;
}
```

So writing a for loop to fill the columns of the array would be the same sort of code that `Arrays.fill()` is giving you.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that `Arrays.fill()` has and advantage against `for()`, like `System.arraycopy()` has.